# Sharing printer with remote Windows system

Tags: linux, windows, print-server

I have a Linux computer with HP printer connected through USB. While my friend who lives elsewhere has a Windows 7 laptop.

I would like to share my printer with him due to some important work. Is it possible to share printer over the internet in this cross-platform environment?

Comment: Over the internet or when he comes over and on the same network?

Comment: And which Linux Distro?

Comment: Over the internet and on debian distro

Comment: Did you find a better answer than what was provided?

Comment: Trying your method but it is failing on client side.

Comment: I would need more information than that to diagnose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one method you could use, it is Google Cloud Print, this allows you to add a printer from Chrome Settings that you have connected to your computer and then you can then share this printer using Google to your friend

Here is a step by step instruction: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-set-up-google-print-on-your-chromebook

Quick and Dirty of it:

> Open Chrome, go to Settings > Advanced Settings, Click Add
>   Printers (Might be labeled "Manage", it was on mine)
>  
>   Click Add Printers on the Next Page
>  
>   Click on the Printers you want to Add 
>   Click Manage your printers
>  
>   Select a Printer and  Click Share
>   Send it to your friend

This should allow your friend to access the printer using Chrome
There is also a Google Cloud Print Driver that should allow access to the printer from any application. [Printer Driver Download](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver)

EDIT: I just went through all these steps myself just now to verify it work, Update Answer with the steps I took. I verified that this does work.